# AntiXss.HtmlEncode vs AntiXss.GetSafeHtmlFragment

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Can anyone please let me know the difference between these two?
`AntiXss.HtmlEncode()` vs `AntiXss.GetSafeHtmlFragment()`

Answer (score 9):

**HtmlEcode** actually encodes tags:

```
AntiXss.HtmlEncode("<b>hello</b><script>");
//Output: &lt;b&gt;hello&lt;/b&gt;&lt;script&gt;
```

**GetSafeHtmlFragment** (AntiXss v4.0) returns HTML fragments with tags intact:

```
Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment("<b>hello2</b><script>")
//Output: <b>hello2</b>
```

### Update

Many consider the latest version of [Microsoft's AntiXSS library broken](https://eksith.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/antixss-4-2-breaks-everything/). I've started using [HTML Sanitizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlSanitizer/) as a decent replacement.

Comment: well, GetSafeHtmlFragment doesn't really returns the HTML fragments intact, it does 2 things:
- properly form malformed html
- remove html tags not on whitelist

Comment: Unfortunately, `AntiXSS.GetSafeHtmlFragment()` turned to be vulnerable in older versions and useless in newer version (it now strips almost all HTML tags possible and became unusable) - [more details here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103360/getsafehtmlfragment-removing-all-html-tags)

Comment: A note for future readers: the `AntiXss` namespace has been deprecated. Use `Encoder` instead. Ex: `Encoder.HtmlEncode("<b>example</b>");`

Answer (score 7):

It should also be mentioned that `antixss.GetSafeHtmlFragment` does encode characters too. A double quote changes to `&quot;`. A plus sign turns into `&#43;` etc.

Comment: Any clue on why that would be the case?

Comment: That's pathetic... Why would I use an anti xss library if it encodes the characters anyways? Scripts can't work if I would encode them for sure. I wonder what I miss.. Encoding is not an option for most of us

Answer (score 5):

I would also add that `GetSafeHtmlFragment` messes up your CSS, by ading **x_** in front of styles, and removes your HTML entity encoding.  It is a less than beautiful thing.

Herc

Comment: (AntiXss v4.2.0)
"The HTML Sanitizer now removes all CSS from the <head> section of an HTML page. If a <style> tag is discovered in the body of an HTML page, or in an input fragment the tag will be removed, but the contents kept, as happens with other invalid tags. If the style attribute is discovered on an element it is removed."