# How to prevent an Injection attack with wysihtml5 editor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, code-injection, wysihtml5

I am using the wysihtml5 editor to allow a user to post messages on a ASP.NET MVC4 discussion forum. These messages are stored in a mssql db and rendered to the screen with Razor syntax:

```
@Html.Raw(post.Html)
```

Although these users are authenticated I wish to ensure that I will not be vulnerable to an injection attack such as the following:

User Posts:

```
<script>alert('Hacked:' + secretInformation)</script>
```

MVC Renders Alert box w/:

```
Hacked: ::secret info::
```

I have allowed the html to be stored in the db by setting in the controller:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

What steps can I take to ensure that I am only rendering clean html code and not vulnerable to attack?

Comment: http://wpl.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a good solution here: [AntiXss 4.2 Breaks everything](http://eksith.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/antixss-4-2-breaks-everything/)

Thanks for the direction Justin. Let's go Microsoft, let's see a solution that doesn't devour ALL my tags!

Comment: Sorry that the AntiXss didn't work for you.  I did have success with it in version 3 of it but haven't found the need for a WYSIWYG in any of the recent apps that I've worked on

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered in previous questions but here is some info:

[AntiXss.HtmlEncode vs AntiXss.GetSafeHtmlFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959136/antixss-htmlencode-vs-antixss-getsafehtmlfragment)

You'll want the sanitzer code since you want html to render but you don't want things like script tags showing up in the markup for security reasons of course.  I also would use the `AntiXss.GetSafeHtmlFragment` before persisting the html in a database.  This will help save you when you use razor's `@Html.Raw`

Comment: Thank you for the response. It seems that GetSafeHtmlFragment is stripping most of: <b>Test<br></b><br><i>test<br></i><br>ddfhdfgh<u>dfghdfghdfghd</u>fghdfgh</div> ---> Testtestddfhdfgh<u>dfghdfghdfghd</u>fghdfgh
Is this really unsafe?

Comment: After some research, it seems that the newest version of Microsoft's AntiXss lib is way way too strict. Have you been able to use this library successfully?

Comment: I haven't used this library since release 3.0.  I was checking to see if you could remove the break and bold tags from the blacklist but don't see much in the way of documentation.